# How can I return accuracy rates for Top N predictions using sklearn's SGDClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am trying to modify the results in this post (How to get Top 3 or Top N predictions using sklearn's SGDClassifier) to get the accuracy rate returned, however I am get an accuracy rate of zero and I can't figure out why. Any thoughts? Any thoughts/edits would be much appreciated! Thank you.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
arr=['dogs cats lions','apple pineapple orange','water fire earth air', 'sodium potassium calcium']
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(arr)
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
Y = ['animals', 'fruits', 'elements','chemicals']
T=["eating apple roasted in fire and enjoying fresh air"]
test = vectorizer.transform(T)
clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier(loss='log')
clf.fit(X,Y)
x=clf.predict(test)

def top_n_accuracy(probs, test, n):
    best_n = np.argsort(probs, axis=1)[:,-n:]
    ts = np.argmax(test, axis=1)
    successes = 0
    for i in range(ts.shape[0]):
        if ts[i] in best_n[i,:]:
            successes += 1
    return float(successes)/ts.shape[0]

n=2
probs = clf.predict_proba(test)

top_n_accuracy(probs, test, n)
```

Comment: I am struggling to understand what you are trying to do here. What is "accuracy rate" for you? Why is the probability of the prediction for each class not enough?

Comment: I need to be able to help report how accurate my classifier is by saying that, for example if my test dataset has 100 cases in it, and my classifier was correct in guessing 80 of the cases ( meaning that each case had at least one match in the  top n results), then the accuracy rate would be 80%.

Comment: I guess my question is more: how do you determine what is a successful classification in your setting? Why do you need this top n?

Comment: Ah I see. So a successful classification would be if at least one out of the top n values was a match, that it would be successful. Does that answer your question? I am creating a recommender, and my client only cares if at least one of my recommendations is a good fit for the classification problem at hand.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. One more thing, when evaluating a model, you need some ground truth labels. Do you have them? It seems to me like ts should not be used, you should rather have the information to which class T belongs and just check if this "true" label appears in one of the top n predictions

Comment: That's a good point. I do have the ground truth labels. But how would I modify this code to achieve that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up figuring this on out, albeit a bit different than the above...

```
# Set Data Location:
data = 'top10000.csv'  

# load the data
df = pd.read_csv(data,low_memory=False,thousands=',', encoding='latin-1')
df = df.dropna()
df = df[['CODE','DUTIES']] #select only these columns
#df = df.rename(index=float, columns={"CODE": "label", "DUTIES": "text"})
df = df.rename(columns={"CODE": "label", "DUTIES": "text"})

#Convert label to float so you don't need to encode for processing later on
df['label']=df['label'].str.replace('-', '',regex=True, case = False).str.strip()
df['label']=df['label'].str.replace('.', '',regex=True)
#df['label']=pd.to_numeric(df['label'])
df['label']=df['label'].str[1:].astype(int)
#df['label'].astype('float64', raise_on_error = True)

#split data into testing and training
train_x, valid_x, train_y, valid_y = model_selection.train_test_split(df.text, df.label,test_size=0.33, random_state=6)

#reset the index 
valid_y = valid_y.reset_index(drop=True)
valid_x = valid_x.reset_index(drop=True)

# We will also copy the validation datasets to a dataframe to be able to merge later on
valid_x_df = pd.DataFrame(valid_x)
valid_y_df = pd.DataFrame(valid_y)

# Extracte features 
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(train_x)
X_test_counts = count_vect.transform(valid_x)

# Define the model training and validation function
def TV_model(classifier, feature_vector_train, label, feature_vector_valid, valid_y, valid_x, is_neural_net=False):

    # fit the training dataset on the classifier
    classifier.fit(feature_vector_train, label)

    # predict the top n labels on validation dataset
    n = 5
    #classifier.probability = True
    probas = classifier.predict_proba(feature_vector_valid)
    predictions = classifier.predict(feature_vector_valid)

    #Identify the indexes of the top predictions
    top_n_predictions = np.argsort(probas, axis = 1)[:,-n:]

    #then find the associated SOC code for each prediction
    top_class = classifier.classes_[top_n_predictions]

    #cast to a new dataframe
    top_class_df = pd.DataFrame(data=top_class)

    #merge it up with the validation labels and descriptions
    results = pd.merge(valid_y, valid_x, left_index=True, right_index=True)
    results = pd.merge(results, top_class_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)

    # Top 5 results condiions and choices
    top5_conditions = [
        (results.iloc[:,0] == results[0]),
        (results.iloc[:,0] == results[1]),
        (results.iloc[:,0] == results[2]),
        (results.iloc[:,0] == results[3]),
        (results.iloc[:,0] == results[4])]
    top5_choices = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

    # Fetch Top 1 Result
    top1_conditions = [(results.iloc[:,0] == results[4])]
    top1_choices = [1]

    # Create the success columns
    results['Top 5 Successes'] = np.select(top5_conditions, top5_choices, default=0)
    results['Top 1 Successes'] = np.select(top1_conditions, top1_choices, default=0)

    #Print the QA 
    print("Are Top 5 Results greater than Top 1 Result? (answer must be True): ", (sum(results['Top 5 Successes'])/results.shape[0])>(metrics.accuracy_score(valid_y, predictions)))
    print("Are Top 1 Results equal from predict() and predict_proba()? (answer must be True): ", (sum(results['Top 1 Successes'])/results.shape[0])==(metrics.accuracy_score(valid_y, predictions)))
    print(" ")
    print("Details: ")
    print("Top 5 Accuracy Rate (predict_proba)= ", sum(results['Top 5 Successes'])/results.shape[0])
    #print("Top 5 Accuracy Rate (np.mean)= ", np.mean(np.array([1 if valid_y[k] in top_class[k] else 0 for k in range(len(top_class))])))
    print("Top 1 Accuracy Rate (predict_proba)= ", sum(results['Top 1 Successes'])/results.shape[0])
    print("Top 1 Accuracy Rate = (predict)", metrics.accuracy_score(valid_y, predictions))

# Train and validate model from example data using the function defined above
TV_model(LogisticRegression(), X_train_counts, train_y, X_test_counts, valid_y_df, valid_x_df)
```

I'm sure it could be more computationally efficient, so any suggestion on how I could transform the accuracy rate calculation into a one liner like was suggested in the comments above would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

arr=['dogs cats lions','apple pineapple orange','water fire earth air', 'sodium potassium calcium']
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(arr)
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
Y = ['animals', 'fruits', 'elements','chemicals']
T=["eating apple roasted in fire and enjoying fresh air", "I love orange"]
test = vectorizer.transform(T)

clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier(loss='log')
clf.fit(X,Y)
x=clf.predict(test)

n=2
probs = clf.predict_proba(test)

topn = np.argsort(probs, axis = 1)[:,-n:]
```

Here I introduce the ground truth label vector (these are numeric indices, you need to map ["elements", etc] to [0,1,2 etc]. Here I assumed your test example belongs to elements.

```
y_true = np.array([2,1])
```

This should then compute your accuracy

```
np.mean(np.array([1 if y_true[k] in topn[k] else 0 for k in range(len(topn))]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I don't quite follow the logic though. Why do you compute the mean?

Comment: The mean computes how many successful predictions there are (according to your definition) divided by the sample size. As a result, if you have 8 correct predictions out of 10, you'll have 80% accuracy

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you @maximeKan! Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Maximekan, unfortunatley this compuation is giving me a 0 result. However this df option gives me the correct one...

Comment: @Statmonger, the above code works, I don't understand why it would return something unexpected for you

Comment: Interesting. Let me post an updated example using that function and get your thoughts on why I might be getting incorrect results. Perhaps I made an adjustment somewhere that affected it.

Comment: Hi @MaximeKan I updated the code in my answer below to show how I applied your technique. It is still giving me a 0 result. Did I apply correctly?