# Get the probability of a sample in sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression instead of class label

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am using `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` for a text classification project. With the features I have extracted, the samples mostly receive a low probability score. Therefore, when I use the `predict()` those samples always classified to class 0. But what I want to do is get the actual probabilities for samples and choose the top 25%-30% based on the probability score. How do I get the probability score for a sample? In linear regression, the `predict()` provides the actual output. But it is not the case for logistic regression. I am not restricted to sklearn. A different package also works.

To make it more clear, what I want from the predict function is to return actual probability value (output of the sigmoid function) instead of the class label like linear regression predict function.

Comment: You can use `clf.predict_proba`, sort your probabilites in descending order and extract the top-n. Check the answer I have posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54875765/sklearn-return-top-3-classes-from-logistic-regression/54895380#54895380

Comment: @panktijk: But `predict_proba()` returns the probability of choosing a particular class, not the probability for that sample!! Am I correct? What I want is the output of the sigmoid function (the trained model). I was going through the different functions in the module. But nothing seems to provide the output that I wanted.

Comment: It returns the probability of choosing a particular class for each sample. Can you provide some more details about your data format and what's the exact output you are looking for?

Comment: @panktijk Assume `f1, f2` are the features of a sample. When those values go through the model the intermediate output is a probability value since the sigmoid output is [0, 1]. Then based on the probability, the model assigns the class. Say if for 0.7, class 1 or for 0.2, class 0. I want 0.7 or 0.2 instead of class. Because my intermediate outputs are mostly below 0.5, which makes the classifier to select class 0. Therefore, the trick is to pick the top 25%-30% samples with the highest probability.

Comment: Yes that is what `clf.predict_proba` will give you.